# purpose of .rel.dyn section in ELF Android system libraries

Tags: android, elf, prelink

I am trying to process the `.rel.plt` section of certain Android system libraries and I can find the address of the functions quite easily.

However I am not sure of what to make out of the entries of the `.rel.dyn` section.  Does this section contain functions as well ? The `.got.plt` table present in X86 libraries is missing in the ARM Android libraries. Not sure if those are required as well.

The android linker code mentions that the system libraries are prelinked and loaded at fixed addresses. How does that play into processing the `.rel.plt` and the `.rel.dyn` section.

The question more broadly is around understanding the Android ARM based system libraries and the `.rel.dyn` , `rel.plt` and `.got.plt` sections with the added issue of prelinking thrown in.

Answer (score 1):

I think this project will help you a lot. https://github.com/shoumikhin/ELF-Hook
this guy just made the method logged here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70302/Redirecting-functions-in-shared-ELF-libraries works at ARM Android platform